# log file removed while redirecting stdout

Tags: c, unix

I have some code, where I do redirect `stdout` to a `logfile` (the usual, `dup, open, and dup2`) and then revert back `stdout`. This works fine as long as I have some `C` code
in between, when I call `system()` and execute some `shell/perl` scripts, I see that the `logfile` gets removed at the end of execution! (the scripts being invoked don't have the `logfile` name, and don't do any `unlink`)
I can see the `logfile` being written *while* the scripts are getting executed.

The code block is like this:

```
 /redirect-stdout-to-logfile/
  system(scripts);
  /reset-stdout/
```

I want to capture all the messages to `stdout` into `logfile`.
Any help to debug further, or hints greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell what's wrong without having the source code.

It seems that your *"reverting back"* the `stdout` is not complete before you call `system()`.

What comes to my mind is using the `exec` family instead of `system` because `exec` is aware of the file descriptors that your process holds when invoking an external program. (Though in this case the file descriptor is intended to be closed.)